# Generate file that contains a list of all files in a directory on linux

Tags: linux, shell

I know how to do this on windows, but I want to create a list of files that are in a directory on a linux machine, either as a txt or csv file. Or is there a way to save the output of a command rather than showing it on screen? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ls` lists the files in a folder, check `man ls` for options. To save the output of a shell command use redirection, e.g.:

```
ls > list.txt
```

or

```
ls -l > list.txt
```

etc.

Comment: @grasshopper If you are going to parse that file later, keep in mind that Unix filenames can contain all kinds of whitespace.